# How can I recite the holy Qur'an when I can't keep my ablution?

Tags: wudu

I have a problem that whenever I make ablutions it breaks within no time due to the winds/hissing sound which comes from my private parts.

So please tell me how I can overcome this problem? And also tell me: Can I continue to recite (make talawat) the holy Qur'an even when my ablution breaks?

Answer (score -1):

If it happens to you ONLY after ablutions , then this is only وسواس scruples from the devil, so forget it and it will vanish. But if not, and unintentional, then it is medical disorder. In either case , you make only one ablution for every salat , and do not repeat it ever . Make one ablution , and go directly to your prayer and do not give attention to any hisses or wind, and pray as much as you want , and read Quran as you wish. When you hear the next Athan, just renew your ablution only once.  Islam wants us to live free and happy life, thanks to God.

God bless you :)

Comment: The person down grading an answer should give reasons.